# is it possible to define a verbatim{} command?

Tags: verbatim

Is it possible to define a `verbatim{}` command  that I could use instead of the environment?

```
\begin{verbatim}
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

As Stefan has said, `fancyvrb` is usually the way to go. However, it’s not straightforward to use in an environment since the relevant macro is undocumented<sup>1)</sup>.

Here’s a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{codeframe}[1]
  {
    % First, we tell fancyvrb that we're inside a verbatim environment.
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \textbf{Source code ``#1'':}\\
    % Now we start the actual environment:
    \begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]%
  }
  {\end{Verbatim}}

\begin{document}
\begin{codeframe}{example}
  this->is(a[source]).code();
\end{codeframe}
\end{document}
```

The comment `%` right behind the `\begin{Verbatim}…` is important – otherwise, the compiler will complain with horrible, undecipherable error messages. The same will happen for any other error you make, so be careful.

The `\VerbatimEnvironment` command is equally crucial, and undocumented.

---

<sup>1)</sup> For simple cases, using the (documented) `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment` may be enough, but the above example cannot be written with it.

Comment: This creates a verbatim environment, not a verbatim command, which I think the OP wanted.

Comment: **Note for reader:** It's **V**erbatim with a capital **V**, not **v**erbatim.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use `\verb`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 Foo \verb|\bar| baz
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought of the inline \verb, but I need something that can span over several lines.

Comment: @landroni In many (but not all) ways, `\detokenize{}` can emulate `verbatim`, and it includes line breaking.

Answer (score 3):

If you need further functionality, have a look at the [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package, it provides further environments and commands for flexible handling of verbatim text.