# Frame line width within DefineVerbatimEnvironment

Tags: verbatim, rules, fancyvrb

I am trying to define an environment which requires a frame line as wide as \textwidth

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
 {code}{Verbatim}{...,frame=lines,%
               xleftmargin=7pt,fontsize=...}
```

I am not sure how I could constrain the width of the line?

Comment: Although I can guess you're using `fancyvrb`, it is better to provide a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) here.

Answer (score 4):

One can modify [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1277/15925) to a related question as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{code}
  {
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \vskip\baselineskip\hrule
    \begin{Verbatim}[xleftmargin=7pt]%
  }
  {\end{Verbatim}\hrule\vskip\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{code}
  Test the verbatim.  
  Here is some more.
\end{code}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

`\hrule` on its own will produce a line of length `\textwidth`, however, it only adds a minimal amount of vertical space.  This is the reason for putting in the `\vskip`'s.  You may well want to adjust the size of these spaces (or use `\smallbreak`, etc.) and you may also want to add some negative `\vskip` amount just after the first rule and just before the last.  E.g. the following gives spacing closer to that obtained from `\begin{Verbatim}[frame=lines]`:

```
\newenvironment{code}
  {
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \vskip18pt\hrule\vskip-10pt\hskip0pt
    \begin{Verbatim}[xleftmargin=7pt]%
  }
  {\end{Verbatim}\vskip-3pt\hrule\vskip18pt}
```

If you need the rules to be of different thickness you can write something like `\hrule height 2pt` instead.