# define a newcommand that will put text in verbatim

Tags: macros, verbatim

For making a report of my work, I am facing a problem of writing varbatim too frequently. So, I need a workout.
Say, I define a newcommand as (for example)

```
\newcommand{\uve}{\textbf{In verbatim}}  %there must be something more
```

now, if I invoke

```
\uve <some text>
```

the effect should be as

```
\textbf{in verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
<some text>
\end{verbatim}
```

I tried using

```
\providecommand{\uve}[1]{\\\textbf{In Verbatim:~}\begin{verbatim}{#1}\end{verbatim}}
```

and failed, with error:
Runaway argument?

```
{/}\end {verbatim}<some text>^^M\stat Complete\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text>
```

Kindly help.

**Edit after 3 comments**
For my present purpose, `\verb` is sufficient. but, I need to define an environment (sorry, not a command as I put in OP) that will give me:

```
\begin{verbenv}
 some text
\end{verbenv}
```

will directly give me:

```
**In verbatim:** Some text
```

Comment: related: [is it possible to define a verbatim{} command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1266/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton  I had thought the point was about macro vs. environment.  But I see your point.  I will delete my prior comment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Using that example directly will need me to add some more text as `\begin{codeframe}{example}` ... not much save in typing.

Comment: The environment `verbatim` is pretty special, since it must end with `\end{verbatim}`. Hence, taking this environment as a part of a control sequence or new environment will get an ERROR. The package `fancyvrb` will help you.

Comment: Does `<some text>` contain any weird characters?

Comment: a lot of `_` and `/` as it is normal in linux filename and paths

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just define a new environment. The simplest way is with the `verbatim` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newenvironment{inverb}
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}\noindent\textbf{In verbatim}\nopagebreak
  \verbatim}
 {\endverbatim}

\begin{document}

Something before
\begin{inverb}
some text
\end{inverb}
Something after

\end{document}
```

With `fancyvrb` you can do more customizations.

[image]